# Can you "Step Up" 15 feet if you have Jaunt Boots?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats

The [Step Up](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/step-up-combat---final) feat says:

> Benefit: Whenever an adjacent foe attempts to take a 5-foot step away
>   from you, **you may also make a 5-foot step** as an immediate action so
>   long as you end up adjacent to the foe that triggered this ability. If
>   you take this step, you cannot take a 5-foot step during your next
>   turn. If you take an action to move during your next turn, subtract 5
>   feet from your total movement.

[Jaunt Boots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-jaunt) say:

> Three times per day, on command for 1 round **when the wearer makes a
>   5-foot step**, he can move up to 15 feet. This movement does not provoke
>   attacks of opportunity.

So wearers with Step Up get a 15-foot jaunt whenever an adjacent foe makes a 5-foot adjust.  I am reading that right aren't I?

---

UPDATE

Thanks for answers.  However, on a related note: I'm not convinced that it's a standard action to activate.  I know it says "on command" etc. but I think D'arandriel nailed it on [this](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pb85?How-are-Jaunt-Boots-supposed-to-work) forum post when he said:

> With all due respect to SKR, I can't imagine that the intent is to use a standard action to move 15 feet. It seems clear that the intent is to substitute 15 feet of movement instead of a 5 foot step up to 3 times per day, otherwise it's a completely useless item.

IMHO it's a Use Activated item with a command word:

> Many use-activated items are objects that a character wears. Continually functioning items are practically always items that one wears. A few must simply be in the character's possession (meaning on his person). However, some items made for wearing must still be activated. **Although this activation sometimes requires a command word (see above), usually it means mentally willing the activation to happen**. The description of an item states whether a command word is needed in such a case.

Comment: The description for Jaunting boots has been changed and the question seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say **yes** as long as you end adjacent to your foe at the end of your 15 feet of movement. The tactical benefits would be amazing because not only do you keep the target threatened, you setup a potential flank attack for your friends the next round.

Answer (score 4):

#### The [*jaunt boots*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-jaunt)' wearer can take a 15-ft. step instead of a [5-ft. step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step) even when using with the feat [Step Up](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/step-up-combat---final)

Of course, the wearer must adhere to the limitations of the feat Step Up, ending up adjacent to the target after taking that 15-ft. 5-ft. step.

However, the wearer should be aware that, because the *jaunt boots* are a [command-word activated](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Using-Items) magic item, activating the *jaunt boots* takes a standard action. This means, for example, instead of *not* using the *jaunt boots*, making a full attack, and taking an immediate action to take a 5-ft. step to stay adjacent to the foe that stepped away, the wearer takes a standard action to activate the *jaunt boots*, takes a move action to do something else, and then can take an immediate action to take a 15-ft. 5-ft. step to end up adjacent to the foe that steps away. Because of a creature's inability to activate the *jaunt boots* and attack in the same turn, most creatures will find that 7,200 gp is better spent elsewhere, but for a creature that concentrates on area denial, for example, the *boots* can be worthwhile.

Comment: Caveat to the caveat: the effect lasts for a round, so the wearer of the boots could activate the power, 5-ft step (or even 15-ft step) up to the target, then use Step Up to follow the target and get around them via the 15-ft movement from the boots.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and raising the action requirement bugbear!  I've looked into some forum posts on that subject and updated my question with my current thinking on the subject.  I've not replied here in the comment in more detail because I can't format comments as I'd like.

Comment: @Vivamort It's cool. My concern is if you try to use the *jaunt boots* in a Pathfinder Society game; the GM'd find the [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pb85?How-are-Jaunt-Boots-supposed-to-work#10) with the developer saying it works like this answer says it works, and the tactics you developed for your PC go out the window, which would suck. But in your home game with a generous GM who's willing to house rule stuff? Who cares? Have fun. `:-)` (That the question's marked **Answered in the FAQ**, and [it's not](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gg) is just weird, though.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Would it be worth noting that in your link is the errata'd version of the item?

Comment: @Zarus Comments on the question say the *jaunt boots* new description has rendered the question invalid. I'm not sure this Q&A mandates further curation. I mean, I can do it, but I'm not sure it helps anyone *now.* It may be better to leave as-is for historical and research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this part:

> so long as you end up adjacent to the foe that triggered this ability.

I’d say no. You can command the jaunt boots and move up to 15 feet so long as you end up adjacent to the foe. If by some other effects the 5-foot-move of the foe needs you to move more than 5 feet to get adjacent, then these boots might help, otherwise I don't see a use here.

Comment: Yes, but you can follow him and than go around him 10 more feet, don't you? The boots explicitly allow you not a 15-feet step but a movement of that length.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. The feat clearly states you must end up adjacent at the end of the Step Up movement, it is a major limitation of the feat. Now, I am not sure that that in anyway makes it useless, With 15 feet you now have enough movement to get in-front/beside of the foe, instead of just following behind.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I can see why. You comment says what you can do with this feat, but the answer does not.